# Predicate Logic proof of validity

Tags: solution-verification, predicate-logic

I have been trying to proof if the following predicate logic formal is valid or not. Having trouble proving it because it has multiple variables.

(∀ ()) ∨ ∃((∀ (, ) ∨ ()) ⇒ ∃∀  (, ))

tried to simplify the formula:

(∀ ()) ∨ ∃((∀ (, ) ∨ ()) ⇒ ∃∀  (, ))

(∀ ()) ∨ ((∃ ∀ (, ) ∨ ∃ ()) ⇒ ∃∀  (, ))

(∀ ()) ∨ ( ∃ ∀ ((, ) ∨ () ⇒ ∃  (, )))

....

I have a feeling that it is non valid for having ∃ () in the implication, that shows that y can be false in  (, ). Would appreciate it if someone can help me explain how to solve this kind of formula.

Comment: Are you trying to prove "∀ ()) ∨ ∃((∀ (, ) ∨ ()) ⇒ ∃∀  (, )," or are you trying to simplify that statement? If it's the former, then there's no way to prove it unless we know what the statements $P$, $Q$, and $R$ are.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's a non-sequitur. How is $P$ related to either $Q$ or $R$. There is no way you can prove that sort of conditional where there is no connection between predicates unless the consequent is a tautology, or the antecedent is a contradiction. It's obviously invalid.

Comment: ... Or a typo....

Comment: @GrahamKemp Could be a typo, but I can't assume it is. Highly improbable that every subsequent line has the same "typo." That said, **assuming that the question has no typos**, the conditional does not hold.

Comment: Ok that's why I was very confused because I have never seen this type of formula. Thanks for the answer. there is no typo